# Weyl's criterion for finding the essential spectrum. Necessary and sufficient?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

In this [book](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Egerald/ftp/book-schroe/),  Lemma 2.16, it is stated:

[image]

However, in the [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387945019) it is claimed that this is actually an if and only if criterion:

[image]

So in the first reference the Weyl sequence need not have a zero weak limit, and there is not an "if and only if" claim. I believe only the latter is correct. But am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't really know the answer, but: the first book is mostly concerned with self-adjoint operators, for which the spectrum is always contained in the real line, and so every point of it is on the boundary. Indeed, the spectrum is taken to be a subset of the complex plane. Therefore, I would not be surprised if the first book has overlooked this issue here.

Comment: Right! Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment,

In the first book $A$ is any closed operator. The converse is not true if $z$ is not a boundary point: Consider the right-shift operator, $0\in\sigma(A)$ but $\|(A-0)\psi_n\|=\|\psi_n\|=1$, so there does not exist a Weyl sequence.

In the second book the definition of the Weyl's criterion requires $u_n\overset{w}\to0$, and in the theorem $A$ is selfadjoint. The converse is true, as self-adjoint
operators do not have residual spectrum.